# Finding the point with minimum x-ordinate, lying between two y-ordinates

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms, search-trees

Given a set of points $P=p_1,p_2,..p_n$ in $R^2$ in where $p_i=(x_i,y_i)$,finding the point with smallest x-ordinate having y-ordinates between $y_1$ and $y_2$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are given as inputs. I can compare the point with other points which gives me an $O(n)$ time algorithm ? Can this be improved any further ?

Comment: In a simple list ordered from left to right, I can find the leftmost in $O(1)$: specify *what* is represented *how*.

Comment: The answer depends on how the input (the list of points) is represented, and can't be answered without that information.  If you'd like your question to be answered, please [edit] it to provide the requested information.  Also, when you say $O(n)$, $O(n)$ what?  $O(n)$ time?  $O(n)$ comparisons?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you assume something more. Without further assumptions, if you don't check all $n$ values, the minimum can be some of the unchecked points.

If you know there is just one minimum in (sorted) range, a variant of binary search (the minimum is the point where $x_{k - 1} > x_k < x_{k + 1}$ or one of the endpoints; if $x_k > x_{k + 1}$ the minimum is to the right, and so on) gets it in time $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 1):

If the points are provided in an arbitrary order (not sorted or anything), then no, you cannot do better than $O(n)$ time.  You must examine every point.  This is easily proven using an adversary argument: if there is any point your algorithm doesn't inspect, then that point could have had a valid $y$-value and a smaller $x$-value than whatever your algorithm outputs, meaning that any such algorithm will have inputs on which it outputs the wrong answer.

Comment: What if we presort the points in order of the x-ordinates in ascending order ?

Comment: @ArkapravaPaul, I can only answer the question that was asked, and that is not part of the problem specification in the answer.  I believe you should be able to figure out the answer to that variant as well on your own: try adapting the ideas in my answer.  What's the fastest algorithm you can find?  Can you come up with an adversary argument?

Answer (score 1):

A [Computational Geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry#Geometric_query_problems) answer would include a description of a data structure and analysed algorithms for preprocessing/set-up and queries.
There is Edward McCreight's [Priority Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_search_tree), use a min heap on $x$ with $y$ medians for telling left from right. (The first point you encounter between $y_1$ and $y_2$ is the one with the lowest $x$ in range.)
*Not* storing the additional median in each node, but using the point's coordinate works almost as well *for well behaved sets*.

Comment: Been there, done that more than one third of a century ago.